# jquery-bootgrid how to hide column

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How do I hide a column on a boot grid?

I've tried to hide the ID column like this:

```
<data-column-id="token" data-identifier="true" data-type="string"  visible="false">token<>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you need to write it like this,

```
<data-column-id="token" data-identifier="true" data-type="string" data-visible="false">
```

read detail here,
http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation

Comment: It looks like this removes the column completely from the DOM, rather than simply hiding it.

Comment: @TimKelly yes, and I think this is not be the proper behavior. Setting something to *invisible* is not the same as completely removing/deleting it. Anyway, I wanted an invisible column for my **ID**, since this makes the tr's `data-dow-id` get the ID value from my ID column, I could achieve what I wanted.

Comment: In my experience, is ... lets say you have 5 columns called ID, User, Title, Description, Date and you want to hide ID and User. When you then click on "Edit", what shows is Date in the Title input, and Description and Date are blank. I've not found an easy way to avoid this. As TimKelly stated. it seems to be removed from the DOM entirely.

Comment: this is just hide column but dropdown menu still show cheked. 
this way how i resolve this: $('input[name=xxx]').trigger("click"); 
xxx is your "data-column-id" name "th" in table. and then i put that code on event load of bootgrid with check for only one process at the first load pange html.

Answer (score 1):

This will help someone in the future. Am posting as a answer by providing a link to it because sometimes we won't read the comments section.
Answer [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013794/jquery-bootgrid-hiding-columns)

```
<style>
 {
.HideColHead
{
display: none
}
.HideCol
{
display: none
}
</style>


<th data-column-id="ID" data-header-css-class="HideColHead" data-css-class="HideCol">ID</th>
<th data-column-id="User" data-header-css-class="HideColHead" data-css-class="HideCol">User</th>
```

This will simply hide the column not removes from the DOM

Comment: I ended up using class and data-header-css-class for the <th elements.   The data-header-css-class appears to take over once the grid gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

optional.

method 1. update Bootgrid to version 1.3 and 
set "data-visible"

```
<th data-column-id="Id" data-visible="false">Id</th>
```

//----------------------------------

method 2.(old version)
use Jquery to trigger hide/show column tool.

```
 <table id="grid-keep-selection" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-column-id="id_col1" data-order="desc" data-width="4.3%">id_col1</th>
                <th data-column-id="id_col2" data-order="desc" data-width="4.3%">id_col2</th>
                <th data-column-id="id_col3"  data-order="desc" data-width="4.3%">id_col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

//-----------------------------------------------

```
var check_first_load = 0; //--> for set default column.
$("#grid-keep-selection").bootgrid({
    ajax: true,
    post: function ()
    {
        return {
            id: "xx"
        };
    },
    url: "api/data/xx.php",
    formatters: {
        "commands": function(column, row)
        {
            return '<a> xxx </a>';
        }
    }
    ,labels: {
        noResults: "where are my results"
    }

}).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function()
{
    //--> for set default hiding column.
    if(check_first_load == 0){
        check_first_load++;

        $('input[name=id_col1]').trigger("click");
        $('input[name=id_col2]').trigger("click");
        $('input[name=id_col3]').trigger("click");
    }
});
```