# jQuery BootGrid - Hiding columns with data-visible="false" removes from DOM

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom, visibility

With BootGrid, you can hide columns by using data-visible="false" in your th column definitions. This creates a problem in that, rather than just hiding the column, it appears to remove it from the DOM.
**Columns** (First two do not show)

```
<tr>
    <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true" data-visible="false">ID</th>
    <th data-column-id="User" data-visible="false">User</th>
    <th data-column-id="Title">Title</th>
    <th data-column-id="Description">Description</th>
    <th data-column-id="Expire" data-formatter="expire" data-sortable="true">Expire</th>
    <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
</tr>
```

**The Problem**
With ID and User set to data-visible="False" their values are inaccessible.
Using data-visible="false" seems to make these fields non-existant altogether. I need to be able to access these values.

Comment: Certainly, as popular as BootGrid is, I would think someone has tackled this before. In my book, this is a pretty big design flaw in an otherwise great bit of code. Or perhaps perhaps someone knows a jQuery grid structure that would work better. Or maybe I should just bite the bullet and write my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two data parameters: header-css-class and css-class the usage of which is not well explained in the documentation I read.
I set up two classes with display:none, which I named "Hidecolhead" and HideCol".
Then, in the columns I do not want to display (ID and user) in the grid, I have

```
<th data-column-id="ID" data-header-css-class="HideColHead" data-css-class="HideCol">ID</th>
<th data-column-id="User" data-header-css-class="HideColHead" data-css-class="HideCol">User</th>
```

The values in these row columns are now available.